# How to get the count of Azure Data Factory datasets, triggers, pipelines and linked services?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-factory, azure-cli

I have created Azure Data Factory and then added datasets, triggers, pipelines and linked services into it. I want to know the count of datasets, triggers, pipelines and linked services using PowerShell or any other alternative way.

Comment: Does the DataFactory UI not show that?. Assuming just a count as you mentioned an alternative way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Count datasets**

```
PS /home/abhishek> $datasets = Get-AzDataFactoryV2Dataset -ResourceGroupName "rg_name" -DataFactoryName "df_name"
PS /home/abhishek> $datasets.count
3
```

**Count triggers**

```
PS /home/abhishek> $triggers = Get-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName "rg_name" -DataFactoryName "df_name"
PS /home/abhishek> $triggers.count
0
```

**Count pipelines**

```
PS /home/abhishek> $pipelines = Get-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName "rg_name" -DataFactoryName "df_name"
PS /home/abhishek> $pipelines.count
3
```

**Count linked services**

```
PS /home/abhishek> $linkedservice = Get-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedService -ResourceGroupName "rg_name" -DataFactoryName "df_name"
PS /home/abhishek> $linkedservice.count
3
```